# How to I retrieve an image from a URL and store it as a Blob in Java (google app engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, blob

I understand how to fetch a URL text page and loop over the results

```
URL url = new URL(this.url);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ....
```

How would I do this to fetch an image and store it as a Blob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get it straight as `InputStream` and use [`PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) to store it. It's binary data, not character data, so a `Reader` would only messup things, you don't want to have that.

In a nutshell:

```
InputStream input = imageUrl.openStream();

// ...

statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO image (content) VALUES (?)");
statement.setBinaryStream(1, input);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

A `PreparedStatement` is really useful. It not only saves you from [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but it also eases setting fullworthy Java objects like `InputStream` in a SQL statement. You can learn more about `PreparedStatement` at the [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm making more progress with the InputStream, however, since I am using Google App Engine, I need to store the Blob to a property in an object.  Could you clarify how I might convert the InputStream to a Blob?

Comment: Why would you ? Just use `PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()` to store `InputStream` into a DB blob field and use `ResultSet#getBinaryStream()` to retrieve `InputStream` from a DB blob field. No need to hassle with `java.sql.Blob` or something tight-coupled like that in Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the little piece I was missing was to 
byte[] theBytes = new byte[input.available()];
input.read(theBytes);

Comment: Trouble!! 1) Don't store it as `byte[]`, it's memory hogging, just stick to `InputStream`. 2) Don't use `input.available()`, it's just returns the next amount bytes available for read without blocking the stream, it doesn't denote the full content length (but which may **by coincidence** do so in case of smaller files).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I abandoned this train of thought soon afterwards, but I will keep your tips handy for the next time.

Comment: @BalusC I'm trying to follow your code but `setBinaryStream(1, input)` has one more int parameter for file size. How do you get around that?

Comment: @mlevit: this parameter is optional.

Comment: Do we need to close the inputStream or will it be closed once the update is executed?

Answer (score 3):

Well what I do to store binary data such as images, is quite simplictic. In my case I deal with uploaded files which get posted to a servlet. Inside the servlet, I get the InputStream on the posted body with request.getInputStream(). However, this works with any kind of InputStreawm, inlcuding one based on an URL. The sample code below shows how to convert that InputStream into google appeninge Blob, which then you can for instance make persistant in the data store.

```
...
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
...

public void InputStreamToBlob(InputStream i) throws IOException {

    ...

    Blob content = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(i));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For an image, instead of reading the buffer line by line, you'll load it in byte array, and save this byte array as a blob.

Comment: That's also possible, it's only possibly more memory hogging than using `InputStream`.